# How to send email through gmail using SMTP-lib and not have it as a BCC?

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I have written code in python using smtp-lib to send email through my gmail account.  The email gets sent, but the email recipient is sent as a BCC.  I think that will work, but I want it to look normal and sending one email should not be sent as BCC, since there are not two email addresses.

I've looked at python documentation for smtp-lib and know I need to use the sendmail() attribute, but there does not look to be any options for my BCC problem.

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = '******@gmail.com'
gmail_password = '*********'

sent_from = gmail_user
to = '*************'
subject = 'TEST TEST TEST'

email_text = 'TEST TEST TEST'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
server.quit()

print('email sent')
```

I want the 'to' address to be sent as a normal email and not to BCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the recipient into the email text:

```
email_text = """
Subject: {}
From: {}
To: {}
TEST TEST TEST
""".format(subject,sent_from,to)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the To: is still empty and BCC has the to variable.

Comment: nm you got it right, i was just confused how to implement it. THanks.